# Bitlocker keeps locking my thumb drive after I have opened it with the password and then have navigated to a child folder

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

I have a Bitlocker-protected thumb-drive.  I must supply a password to open it. Today, after I supply the password, it opens to reveal the root folder in File Explorer, which I expand to reveal the child folders. After a few seconds, File Explorer closes of its own accord, locking the drive again.

Is this some new Windows 10 security feature, where I have to act quickly once I've unlocked the drive?

P.S. I just tried to remove the Bitlocker protection in Control Panel, and it went crazy, opening the root folder, closing it, beeping, telling me that the device did not exist.  I finally managed to pause the decryption.

Comment: "Is this some new Windows 10 security feature, where I have to act quickly once I've unlocked the drive?" - No;  The behavior isn't normal.  If I were to take a wild guess, the device is actually malfunctioning, and the behavior with File Explorer is an indication the device is disconnecting and reconnecting.

Comment: It could be the device as you have suggested.  If it is, a single malfunctioning device can bring Windows 10 to its knees.  The decryption started up again of its own accord after it had been paused and I was subsequently unable to pause it. It just keep flashing a dialog with a progress bar that never made it past 55.7%  It was impossible to get the Pause button to register my click. That's a programming error by Microsoft, where a background I/O process wrests control away from the UI and the user.

Comment: It is not possible to handle every hardware fault that will happen.  Most operating systems fail to handle I/O errors gracefully.  Most fall flat on their head when a drive throws I/O errors, the OS attempts to respond to those errors or simply waits godawful amounts of time to perform I/O due to those errors.

Comment: It is interesting to note that this problem with the thumb drive arose within hours of my setting the Search Indexer to ignore the Bitlocker-protected thumb drive; it had been previously set to ignore but a recent forced upgrade to a major feature update of Windows seems to have undone that setting and turned indexing back on. It took me a while to figure out why an error message kept popping up saying the drive was inaccessible. That error stopped once I updated the Search Indexer to ignore the drive once again.  And now, I have a corrupted thumb drive.

Comment: Windows was probably having a hard time indexing the drive, which is the reason you were being told the drive wasn't accessible, what you describe is the exact behavior I would expect from a drive that is failing and malfunctioning

Comment: Possibly so. But this system was working very stably until Microsoft forced upon it a major feature update, *disguised as a security update*.  They don't deserve the benefit of the doubt when they do *@&$ like that.